In C, There is no buffer overflow in strings
Whenever we store data more than the memory allocated to variable we got some unexpected results.But I declare a character array (name) with size 5 and get value from the user (greater than 5 characters).When i try to print it, I got the same exact output.Here is my program and its output.
char name[5]  ;
printf("Enter Name:");
scanf("%s",name);
printf("Name = %s\nSize = %lu ",name,sizeof(name)/sizeof(char) ) ;


Output:

How this happened ?

It's UB (Undefined behavior). It might seem to work well but you can't rely on it.

Are you aware of "Undefined Behaviour"? What makes your think that it does not explain what you observe? Can you confirm that this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Actually your program use extra stack. If your code is all of your program, on gcc v14 program will crash with segment fault. But if your code have a char v[100];, Your code run correctly. In this situation your program use extra stack and this is undefined behavior.

Please remove picture result from question and add text information. Also your code seems to be in complete. Please add your complete code if it is possible.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

Remember that arrays have a fixed size. If you declare an array of five elements, it will always have five elements. If you put a string into your array, it will not change the size of the array. For example, after strcpy(name, "A") the size of the array will still be 5, but the string length (as returned by strlen(name)) will be 1. String length and array size are not the same thing.

Also see What is undefined behavior and how does it work?

Try to compile with -fsanitize=address and look at the output, it will give you more information about your memory errors

Note that sizeof(name)/sizeof(char) returns the number of elements in the array, not the length of the string. So regardless of what the users enters, this value will always be 5 because you declared name as char[5].
